# TYPO3 9.5.3 - Log errors showing multiple attempts to access non-existing routes

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

In a TYPO3 9.5.3 demo installation I see multiple errors in the log looking this:

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1518472189: The requested page does not exist
```

... and attempts to access sites (which don't exist) like this:

```
typo3_src-9.5.3:

Requested URL: http://demo.domain/ultxswkov.html

typo3_src-9.5.1:

Requested URL: http://demo.domain/hpwymspohv.html   
Requested URL: http://demo.domain/txlkcgnaet.html 
Requested URL: http://demo.domain/contact.php   
Requested URL: http://demo.domain/kontakt.html
Requested URL: http://demo.domain/kontakt.htm
Requested URL: http://demo.domain/kontakt
Requested URL: http://demo.domain/contact-us.html
Requested URL: http://demo.domain/contacts.htm
Requested URL: http://demo.domain/contacts.html
...
```

In all my v.8 installations I never had such log errors. I assume somebody tries to access thoses sites? (For this specific domain I don't have a ssl certificate yet) What's the best practice to do now?

Comment: Is this demo installation online or only on your localhost? If its online, i think its one of those thousand spam bots around the internet which tries to find "interessting" stuff where he can submit some spam emails. If your log has only few entries of this, its "normal" :-D

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+stop+bots+on+your+website

Comment: ... yes ... the site is online. So no additional security precaution needed? Yeah and I only have a couple of entries like this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that error 404 was not logged in TYPO3 8.x into sys_log. Atleast with default configuration. You can check the apache error log to see what happend in the past (with TYPO3 8.x). You should see many similar 404 errors there.

Every website in the internet has evil bots as visitors, so its nothing special with TYPO3 9.x.

The question "no additional security precaution needed?" is hard to answer. As long as your installation is secure, there is no problem.

Security Guidelines: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/Security/Index.html